# MySQL SQL multiple

Tags: mysql, sql

i have problem with my query. I don't know how to write it properly.

Now i have:

```
SELECT i.bpm_id
FROM t_bpm_process i
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM t_rfp_proposal r
    JOIN t_rfp_request AS rfp ON rfp.rfp_id=r.rfp_id 
    WHERE r._astat_code ='awr'
    AND r.status_code!='del'
    AND rfp.bpm_id=i.bpm_id
)
```

In one bpm we have a lot of proposals with unique id. I want to show only rfp_id
which does not have astat_code='awr'.

For example I have:

```
    prop_id rfp_id  _astat_code
    3,400   4,599   shr
    3,401   4,599   shr
    3,398   4,600   shr
    3,399   4,600   shr
    3,402   4,601   shr
    3,403   4,601   awr
```

I want to show only rfp_id 4599, 4600.

The formula should be universal. Because there will be for example 12 rfp_id, so it can not be made only for 3 rfps. Can you help me?

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Comment: it likely would have worked just changing it to `select *` where you have `select 1`.   Edit: no, there is no comparison happening.  ...  Anyway...    

Also, considering selecting an answer to accept.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a NOT IN

```
SELECT i.bpm_id
FROM t_bpm_process i
where i.rfp_id NOT IN (
  select rfp_id  
  from t_bpm_process
  where astat_code='awr'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
select i.bpm_id
from   t_bpm_process  i,
       t_rfp_proposal r,
       t_rfp_request  rfp
where  rfp.bpm_id     = i.bpm_id
and    r.status_code != 'del'
and    r._astat_code  = 'awr'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.bpm_id
FROM   t_bpm_process i
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT rfp.bpm_id
    FROM   t_rfp_proposal r
    JOIN   t_rfp_request rfp ON rfp.rfp_id=r.rfp_id 
    WHERE  r._astat_code ='awr'
      AND  r.status_code!='del'
  ) AS t ON i.bqm_id = t.bqm_id
WHERE t.bqm_id IS NULL
```